# How to handle sessions in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am trying to make a Chatbot with Dialogflow. If I reload or refresh page I want to retain the chat.
I have tried doing it with Iframe but it didn't worked.

Comment: Can you give more details about your project? For example, where are you using your trained chatbot and what is the expected result?

Comment: I am using dialogflow messenger and integrating it with website. I want to retain all the chat within the same website.